# Weird behavior of SOLR range query

Tags: solr

I've got a solr index with approximately 100000 items. 
One field of the index is an integer that can range from 0 to INT_MAX (actually the highest value in the index is 157). I try to do range queries on this field and I get very strange results :

range queries :

- nb_validations:[10 TO *] => returns 40499 items
- nb_validations:[9 TO *] => returns 6 items (**should be at least 40499 ??!!**)
- nb_validations:[8 TO *] => returns 13 items

exact match queries :

- nb_validations:10 => returns 2005 items
- nb_validations:9 => returns 6 items

I have no error in the logs and my solr configuration looks OK. Field is declared as an int and is indexed and stored.

What's wrong with that ? Can my index be corrupted ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the result of `[* TO 10]` then? I wonder isn't the problem with range query syntax itself (not encoding whitespace as `%20`, for example).

Comment: [* TO 10] gives good result (approximately 57000 items, which reflects the distribution on the field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `sint` to store the values and use the field for range queries.

```
<field name="age" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

If you have the field type as integer, Solr still probably treats it as a String.

```
<field name="age" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

[Documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-ALPHA/org/apache/solr/schema/IntField.html) :-

> A legacy numeric field type that encodes "Integer" values as simple
>   Strings. This class should not be used except by people with existing
>   indexes that contain numeric values indexed as Strings. New schemas
>   should use TrieIntField.
>
> Field values will sort numerically, but Range Queries (and other
>   features that rely on numeric ranges) will not work as expected:
>   values will be evaluated in unicode String order, not numeric order.

Comment: Alright, sounds interesting. I'll check that a soon as possible. Do I have to rebuild the index when changing field type ?

Comment: changed field type from integer to sint, solved the problem. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use "int" type, range query will be worked fine.

```
<field name="my_name" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```